# Java class cached in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

When developing my own Java class to use within ColdFusion 8 I stumble upon a problem that ColdFusion doesn't recognize that the *.java or *.class was changed, at least i don't see the change I made appear on the page. Is it some kind of caching issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try using the JavaLoader from RIAForge. It lets to specify a JAR or .class file to load. It doesn't even need to be in the classpath so you can store the JAR in with your CFML if you like. I'm pretty sure its not impacted by caching.

http://javaloader.riaforge.org/

Comment: Great library. But the old version essentially behaved the same way as CF. ie New jars were not detected until you bounce the CF server or with javaLoader, create a new instance. However the new version (1.0 alpha) might be an option. It supports "Dynamic Compilation". But be sure to see http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayPost&ID=212 as well.

Comment: Yea, I guess the idea is that creating a new instance with class loader is what you would have to do. I dont think there would be a way to do with WIHOUT creating a new instance. Or overwriting the existing instance. Maybe if you hooked in some Groovy....

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that "HotDeploy" is not turned off... :)

Comment: is it a jvm argument which has to be given explicitly in order to turn it off?

Comment: Note, this is a good idea for development or test instances, but you probably don't want it for your production site.

Comment: this is supposed to be in the development environment. however, how would i make my production environment notice the change in the class?